# parameter has incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I get the warning "parameter has incomplete type" in the last line. 
But I have no idea why.

```
struct clockClass {
    uint32_t (*getClock) (void);
    bool (*setCorrectionFactor)(uint32_t newCorrectionFactor);
    uint32_t (*getCorrectionFactor) (void);
};

/* Type definition for ::virtualClock  */
typedef struct clockClock ClockClass;

/* VC Synchronization Class */
struct vcSync_sRio {
    bool (*vcSync)(ClockClass me);  /*Warning LINE*/
};
```

Comment: `struct clockClass {` but `typedef struct clockClock ClockClass;`
I see the difference, do you?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? GCC, Visual Studio? Anything else? Any specific warning number?

Comment: @aragaer Nice one! Didn't get it until you pointed it out :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's just a typo: you have defined `struct clockClass` but your `typedef` defines an alias for `struct clockClock`.

Change your `typedef` to: `typedef struct clockClass ClockClass;`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to:

```
bool (*vcSync)(struct ClockClass me);
```

or change the other line to:

```
typedef struct ClockClass ClockClass;
```